# Controlling ftp access with vsftpd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I had vsftpd set up such that I was able to upload files to a VPS I set up.  The only problem is that I could not create directories.  I set up vsftpd to disallow anonymous users, but allow virtual users to connect with their local credentials.  At this point, the error message when I tried to create a folder changed from '550: Create directory failed' (I'm paraphrasing) to '550: Permission denied'.  root owns the /var/www folder, and user with which I was authenticating had read and execute permissions but not write, so it makes sense that I wouldn't be able to create folders or files.

At this point I tried using chown and chmod to recursively change the group ownership to a group that my user was in and give my user write permission. This seemed to work at first - in the SSH session, I was able to cd to /var/www and create a new directory. However, when I tried to log in with my ftp client, I was now denied access.

What's even weirder is when I checked /var/log/vsftpd.log, I see the following lines:

```
Mon Jan  5 00:03:25 2015 [pid 801] CONNECT: Client "73.53.82.111"
Mon Jan  5 00:03:25 2015 [pid 800] [gradinafrica] OK LOGIN: Client "73.53.82.111"
```

...even though the login doesn't seem to work.  What's going on?

**EDIT** (more info):
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Architecture: Virtual private server (?)

When I set up the server, I disallowed logging in as root (as recommended by multiple sources) and set up a different user - 'gradinafrica' - which I added to the sudo group. I'm attempting to use this account for ftp.  I haven't worked with sftp at all.

Here's the contents of vsftpd.conf (comments omitted):

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/var/www/
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: Provide which operating system you using, version, arch, Did you have a separate user for ftp, sftp ?

Comment: anonymous_enable=NO  then why should you have to use anon_upload_enable=YES ?

Comment: Forgot to comment that out.  I am, as I mentioned, a complete newb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get the write permission for your user account in /var/www/ particular user want to be a member of apache or www-data group according to your operating system.

```
write_enable=YES
```

Only use this if you have added a user with web root directory as it home directory

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Comment: A combination of adding 'gradinafrica' to 'www-data' and adding 'allow_writeable_chroot=YES' seems to have worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @Infected Root can you explain a little more about `allow_writeable_chroot=YES`? I searched but I can't find any documentation about it.